# stringWithUTF8String is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I got this issue: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const char *' is disallowed with ARC. Which way do I need to use to coreect this problem?

Comment: Post your code to see exactly what you are doing. However check my answer.

Comment: is your variable of type `NSString*`, not `const char *`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't tell without looking at the code but here are my guesses:

If you are passing an NSString you have to put

```
NSString *someStringUTF = @"something";
NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:someStringUTF.UTF8String];
```

If you are passing a core object (Most of the raw objects that start with CF) you have to bridge it by either giving ownership or keeping it.

```
(__bridge_transfer NSString*)yourFoundationObject
```